# How to modify radio buttons in WTForms to be placed horizontally with each other?

Tags: python, html, flask-wtforms

I am a newbie to python flask and WTforms and am working on a project to get my feet wet. I was wondering how does one modify each radio button in a WTForm so that instead of being placed vertically, they could be placed horizontally because to me it seems that I can only modify all of these elements as a whole.

Python code:

```
class CreateForm(Form):

doc=RadioField('Choice of doctor', choices=[('A', 'Dr Tan'), ('B', 'Dr Mok'), ('C', 'Dr Lim')], default='C')
```

HTML code
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

```
  <div class="form-group">
{{ wtf.form_field(form.doc, class="form-control") }}
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked some time ago now (7 months ago at the time I'm answering) but in case anyone else ends up here, this is how I did it.

In your template put this:

```
{{ form.doc.label }}
{% for subfield in form.doc %}
 <tr>
    <td>{{ subfield(class="form-check-input") }}</td>
    <td>{{ subfield.label }}</td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The `class="form-check-input"`is optional, it is just there as you said you are using bootstrap.